# Creating multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

So I need to do a product inventory per warehouse. I'm using ms access as front end and SQL server express as a back end.

The query was working fine when I used ms access as linked back end but when I moved my back end to SQL server express when I run the query, a message box is popping up saying:

> ODBC call failed. [Microsoft][Sql Server Native CLient 11.0][Sql Server] The multipart identifier "Dbo.tbl_Warehouse.warehouse_ID" could not be bound.(#4104)

So made a query (**qry_Product_Warehouse**) where each warehouse contains every product

```
SELECT tbl_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID, tbl_Product.Product_ID
FROM tbl_Warehouse, tbl_Product;
```

I also have a union query (**Qry_Product_Transactions**) where all the product transactions are, including which warehouse it was transacted. Like *[Transaction_Type],[Date],[Product],[Location],[quantity]*

Then I have a table (**tbl_product_Quantity**) where if the company will do a monthly stock recounting, they will just enter the *[Stock_Recount_Date],[Stock_Recount_Quantity],[product],[warehouse]*.

The problem is the message box is popping up when I run the query like this (Simplified Version of Joins):

```
[qry_Product_Warehouse].[warehouse_ID] left join [qry_Product_Transactions].[Location]
[qry_Product_Warehouse].[warehouse_ID] left join [tbl_Product_Quantity].[warehouse]
[qry_Product_Warehouse].[product_ID] left join [qry_Product_Transactions].[Product]
[qry_Product_Warehouse].[Product_ID] left join [tbl_Product_Quantity].[Product]
```

Actual Query is this:

```
SELECT qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID, 
       qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID, 
       CDbl(Nz(IIf(IsNull([tbl_Product_Quantity].[Stock_Recount_Date]),
       Sum([qry_Product_Transaction].[qty]),[tbl_Product_Quantity].[Stock_Recount_Quantity]+Sum(IIf([qry_Product_Transaction].[Date]>[tbl_product_quantity].[Stock_Recount_Date],[qry_Product_Transaction].[Qty],0))),0)) AS Current_Qty

FROM (qry_Product_Warehouse LEFT JOIN qry_Product_Transaction ON (qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID = qry_Product_Transaction.Location) 
    AND (qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID = qry_Product_Transaction.Product)) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Product_Quantity ON (qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID = tbl_Product_Quantity.Product) 
    AND (qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID = tbl_Product_Quantity.Warehouse)


GROUP BY qry_Product_Warehouse.Warehouse_ID, qry_Product_Warehouse.Product_ID, tbl_Product_Quantity.Stock_Recount_Quantity, tbl_Product_Quantity.Stock_Recount_Date;
```

Comment: i have also already tried running it on sql server and it also isnt working.

Comment: What is the error message when you run this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (or Query Analyser). You also have three queries - which one(s) give an error (and what are those errors)?